# HttpURLConnection is throwing exception for Http code 407

Tags: android, httpurlconnection

Im handling all of my requests through `HttpURLConnection` and if I get Http code higher than `300`, Im handling that response as error response and I'm reading parameters sent by server from `errorStream`. This is working fine for all Http errors except 407. I dont know why, but I have whole HttpURLConnection initialization in try catch block and it will catch exception: `exception: java.net.ProtocolException: Received HTTP_PROXY_AUTH (407) code while not using proxy` therefore I cant handle parameters sent by server from errorStream and it will return `unknown error`.

Is there any way how to fix this without throwing exception?

Comment: You appear to be using the HttpUrlConnection from the OkHttp library, as that exception message is particular to it. See https://android.googlesource.com/platform/external/okhttp/+/123333e7759f91b846c58849469b9d0ab21213f6/src/main/java/com/squareup/okhttp/internal/http/HttpURLConnectionImpl.java Perhaps you have the wrong import?

Comment: Nope I have java.net.HttpURLConnection

Comment: Ah, I see, apparently, as of Android 4.4, HttpUrlConnection is a wrapper around OkHttp. Not sure how I missed that....